# Akka (JVM): Serialize an actorref with protobuf within another message

Tags: scala, akka, protocol-buffers

I have the following scala object that I would like to serialize with protobuf:

```
case class Worker(id: String, ref: ActorRef)
```

My understanding is that Akka comes with a ProtobufSerializer that I can use to serialize from/to ActorRef. Therefore I defined the following message in a proto file:

```
message Worker {
    string id = 1;
    bytes ref = 2;
}
```

However the static methods ProtobufSerializer take an ExtentendActorSystem that I do not have at hand when I need to serialize those messages (only an ActorSystem through the context.system attribute of my actor). I am not sure how to actually serialize my object to protobuf and the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure in which cases it is true, but I was able to simply cast my ActorSystem to an ExtendedActorSystem. In my specific case (I am using Akka Persistence with Akka Singleton) it seems to work fine.

Comment: Hey, @Canard how you resolve this problem, we have similar requirements, our message contains ActorRef and wants to serialize.

Comment: Yes I used this: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-remote/src/main/scala/akka/remote/serialization/ProtobufSerializer.scala

Comment: @Canarad are you adding your custom implementation of `parseFrom` and `toByteArray` methods?

Comment: @Canarad if possible, could you please share the example for your solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I do no have the code anymore, I am not working in the same company.

Comment: No problem @Canarad, could you give me an idea, did you used an existing actor system or created a new ExtendedActorSystem for deserializeActorRef?

Comment: As I said in my response I did not need to create another ActorSystem, casting the existing one worked fine.