# Akka doc is unclear about how to get an ExtendedActorSystem to deserialize ActorRef

Tags: akka-cluster

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize ActorRef through protobuf.  According to the Akka doc, the only way to do it is to convert the ActorRef into a String, and convert it back in the remote actor system.

The doc mentions using an `ExtendedActorSystem` to do the deserialization (see [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/serialization.html#serializing-actorrefs)).  However, it is unclear how to get the `ExtendedActorSystem`:

```
// Serialize
// (beneath toBinary)
val identifier: String = Serialization.serializedActorPath(theActorRef)

// Then just serialize the identifier however you like

// Deserialize
// (beneath fromBinary)
// ==== Where is this extendedSystem from? ====
val deserializedActorRef = extendedSystem.provider.resolveActorRef(identifier)
// Then just use the ActorRef
```

**Edit**

I found this question here: [Akka (JVM): Serialize an actorref with protobuf within another message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40773176/842860), which mentions casting an `ActorSystem` to `ExtendedActorSystem`.  Is this the right approach?  Will it always work?

Comment: Also very curious about this

Comment: Hey @stackverflow have you find the solution for ExtendedActorSystem right approch?

Answer (score 1):

dear @stackoverflower,

whenever you use `ActorSystem(...)` it build an instance of `ActorSystemImpl`.

The type-tree looks like:

`ActorSystemImpl extends ExtendedActorSystem`

and

`ExtendedActorSystem implements ActorSystem`

you can use statements like

`val system: ExtendedActorSystem = ActorSystem(...).asInstanceOf[ExtendedActorSystem]`

to access the correct type autocomplete. `ActorSystemImpl` is unfortunately scoped to `[akka]`.